# get cell color in VBA and copy it into a pie-chart

Tags: vba, excel

Could somebody possibly tell me a simple and straightforward way to read the colour of a cell in a worksheet into VBA and then to use this RGB code or what ever to colour a part of a pie chart?

I'm trying

```
    Function rgb_color(cl As Range) As String
Dim rgbc As Long, rc As Long, gc As Long, bc As Long
If cl.Cells.Count = 1 Then
rc = cl.Interior.Color Mod 256
rgbc = Int(cl.Interior.Color / 256)
gc = rgbc Mod 256
bc = Int(rgbc / 256)
Else
End If
End Function

Sub ColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

    Dim Colors

    Select Case i Mod 10
        Case 0
        rgb_color (C2)
        rgb_color (C3)
        rgb_color (C4)
```

So the first part is the function  that gets the RGB code from the cell and I have a variety of charts to color which is the reason I chose different case statements. I know that I could manually do the RGB colours if needed but is there a simple way to use the different rc,bc,gc variables for each of the three cells (C2 to C4) as RGB values? It would look like an array

```
RGB(rc of C2; gc of C2; bc of C2)
same for C3 and C4
```

then the next case with the same procedure?

''######################################################
EDIT from Tim's comment

If I got Tim (comment below) correct I could write

```
Sub ColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

        Dim Colors

        Select Case i Mod 10
        Case 0 
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.For‌eColor.RGB = Range("A1").Interior.Color
```

could somebody potentially correct me if that's wrong?

Comment: This is starting to look a bit familiar from a day or so ago... Anyway, the `Interior.Color` of a cell is a Long data type and you can assign that directly as the fill color of a point in a chart data series. No need to split it up into its 3 components.

Comment: FYI: Rolled back to original version to remove the excessive bolding added in a subsequent edit.

Comment: How would I use Interior.Color(A1) with the case command? Could you provide an example how I could ascribe that to the fill of a colour point in a chart series?

Comment: Tim, I updated the code, is that correct?

Comment: `Points(1)` rather than `Points(x)` (my copy/paste error) but did you try it?

Comment: sorry, no I haven't because I woudl have to rewrite large parts of the script... but with the Points(x) this statement the ActiveSheet.ChartObjects...bit canbe used in the Case statements? So there ia a Active Sheet statement for each part of the pie I would like to colour? And as soon as it goes to the next pie a new case statement is needed?

Comment: If you don't want to try it (how hard is it to write a one-line test procedure?) then I will wait while you reconsider. You don't have to rewrite the whole thing to try a simple method like this.  I'd have to suggest at this point (and based on what I'm assuming are your previous posts) that you need to first get a basic idea of how VBA works before proceeding with this.  There are plenty of very good books out there, and it's well worth the investment of your time.

Comment: So i tried this for a scenario with a single case only. The problem is that VBA complains about a syntax error (I changed x into 1 in the points argument) and highlights the whole lien. I would conclude that I can't do it this way? But why can't I use the same case procedure as before with this line for painting?

Comment: You're passing in `cht` as a parameter to `ColorScheme` but ignoring it?  This is what I mean about needing to get some basic understanding of VBA before going any further.  You need to be able to modify examples provided by people here so that they fit your exact situation.  Without that ability you're making us guess over and over exactly what it is you're trying to do.  That gets frustrating on both sides.

Comment: dear tim I wouldnt ask if it werent really super important I am sorry for the limited capabilities but I would really! appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This shows exactly how to do it (or at least how I would do it).  It's up to you to make it work.

```
Sub Tester()
Dim cht As Chart, x As Long
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

    For x = 0 To 1
        'set pie chart source data
        SetColorScheme cht, x 'this will apply the color scheme
        cht.CopyPicture
        '...paste to point in other chart
    Next x

End Sub

'set the color scheme on the passed chart object
Sub SetColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

    Dim y_off As Long, rngColors As Range
    Dim x As Long

    y_off = i Mod 10
    'this is the range of cells which has the colors you want to apply
    Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("colors").Range("A1:C1").Offset(y_off, 0)

    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        'loop though the points and apply the corresponding fill color from the cell
        For x = 1 To .Points.Count
            .Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                             rngColors.Cells(x).Interior.Color
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what do the comments in the code exactly indicate. The first point where you say set pie chart source date is this a comment on what you have written in th eline below that sentance or is it that a line has to be inserted?

Comment: is there any chance to read the value of the range of this code froma  cell in excel..so that the range value can just be entered and then read from a cell???

Comment: 1. Yes - you need to set the data range  2. Yes - you can do that if you prefer...

Comment: tim, the Sub SetColorScheme returned me an error at Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("colors").Range("A1:C1").Offset(y_off, 0) with the message subscript out of range. DO you have any idea how this error is caused?

Comment: Either there's no sheet named `colors` in the workbook containing the macro, or you've specified an invalid value for `y_off`